# How to configure the path of output directory in xcode 7.3.1 for command line template.

Tags: xcode

I usually use  visual studio where I can easily configure output folder where the executable goes after building my code. However, I am trying to use xcode and started a project with the command line tool template.

After building my code, I could run it from xcode and could see the output in the xcode console. It looks like the binary file (the executable) in not in the project folder and xcode is running the executable from other path.

My question is, how can I configure xcode to put the binary file inside my project directory so that I can easily run it from console manually?

Is it possible to configure my project folder like we do in visual studio?
something line as follows:

```
Project folder
   |- source
   |- debug
   |- release
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, somewhat got the solution.
Though it is not exactly same as visual studio, I could move my build folder to project folder.

Here is how I did it,

In xcode, Goto xcode->preferences
Then in the choose Locations tab.
Then in the Derived data section, click Advanced button.

Select "Custom"
Then from the drop down menu, select "Relative to workspace".